# Functional Analysis, operator theory, eigenvalues of a operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We have

$$T_\alpha:C[a,b]\to C[a,b]$$
$$T_\alpha f= \alpha f$$
where 
$C[a,b]=\{ f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R} \quad f$ is continuous}
and $\alpha\in C[a,b]$ fixed.

Show:

1. Spectrum of $T_\alpha\equiv \sigma(T_\alpha)=Im(\alpha)\equiv$ image of $\alpha$.
2. $T_\alpha$ has eigenvectors iff $\alpha$ is constant in some interval of $[a,b]$.

This is what I have tried to do:

1.I tried to use the fact that $||T_\alpha||=||\alpha||$, then we have this 
$$\sigma(T_\alpha)\subseteq [-||\alpha||,||\alpha||] $$

In the other hand we have

$$Im(\alpha)=[A,B]\subseteq[-||\alpha||,||\alpha||] $$
where $A$ and $B$ is the minim and maxim of $\alpha$ in $[a,b]$.
But with this we can not conclude anything.

2.Considering $$\lambda f = \alpha f$$
first we consider that $\lambda$ is a eigenvalue so $f$ is a associated eigenvector so $f$ is not identically null, i.e. $\exists t_0$ in $[a,b]$ that $f(t_0)\neq 0$. We take the quotient at $t_0$ and we have this:

$$\lambda=\alpha(t_0)$$

How do we conclude that $\alpha$ must be constant at some interval of $[a,b]$ ?

second, if we consider that $\alpha(t)$ is constant in some $[c,d]\subseteq[a,b]$, then we can take $f\equiv 1\neq 0$ and we have this:

$$\lambda=\alpha(t)\quad \forall t \in [c,d]$$

so $\lambda = \alpha(t)$ is a eigenvalue of $T_\alpha$, then $T_\alpha$ has eigenvalues.

Please some help for 1. and left-to-right implication of 2.

Comment: If $\alpha(t)=0$ for all $t\in [c,d]$ ??

Comment: oh oh !  I forgot it.  $\alpha(t)*f(t)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a remark on intuition, rather than precise proofs. The operator $T_\alpha$ is a spectral multiplier and you should therefore think of it as an infinite dimensional analogue of a diagonal matrix. Functional calculus with 
diagonal matrices is trivial: one views them as functions on the set $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ and performs addition and multiplication pointwise. For instance if $A$ is the diagonal matrix with spectrum $\{\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n\}$ then $\sin (A)$ is the diagonal matrix with spectrum $\{\sin(\lambda_1),\ldots, \sin(\lambda_n)\}$ and $(A-\lambda)^{-1}$ for generic $\lambda$ is the diagonal matrix with spectrum $\{(\lambda_1-\lambda)^{-1},\ldots, (\lambda_n-\lambda)^{-1}\}$, provided that this actually defines a bounded operator (i.e. $\lambda\notin\{\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n\}$).

On $C[a,b]$ the situation is quite similar: $\sin(T_\alpha)=T_{\sin \alpha}$ where $\sin \alpha\in C[a,b]$ is given pointwise by $x\mapsto \sin (\alpha(x))$ and for generic $\lambda$, $(T_\alpha-\lambda)^{-1}$, if it is a bounded operator, will be given by $T_{(\alpha-\lambda)^{-1}}$. So the question is: when does pointwise multiplication by the function $x\mapsto (\alpha(x)-\lambda)^{-1}$ define a bounded operator on $C[a,b]$? Clearly the answer is that this happens if and only if $\lambda$ is not in the range of $\alpha$, since otherwise $(\alpha-\lambda)^{-1}$ will have singularities just as $k\mapsto (\lambda_k-\lambda)^{-1}$ has singularities for $\lambda\in\{\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n\}$ in the finite dimensional case.

As for question 2, the hint that Martin Argerami provided is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

1) If $\lambda$ is in the image of $\alpha$, you want to show that $T_\alpha-\lambda I$ is not invertible. If $\alpha(t_0)=\lambda$, consider a continuous $f$ with $f(t_0)=1$. Then $(\alpha(t)-\lambda)g(t)=f(t) $ fails at $t_0$ for all $g$, so $T-\lambda I$ is not onto.

2) Remember that your $f$ is continuous, so it will be nonzero in a whole interval around $t_0$.

Comment: Using 1. we can conclude  $Im(\alpha)$ is in $\sigma(T_\alpha)$, some hint for the other implication ($\sigma(T_\alpha)$ is in $Im(\alpha)$ )?


If we take a element from $\sigma(T)$ and see if that element is or not in $Im(\alpha)$ is complicate, because a element is in $\sigma(T)$ is because $\lambda Id- T$ is:
1. non 1-1
2. non onto.
3. 1-1 and onto but not continuous